# yii2: where do my project's own html, css, js, and php-include files go?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Choices:

1. create an asset bundle (nicely explained by Ivo Renkema at [How do I manage assets in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686904/how-do-i-manage-assets-in-yii2)).  this is what I need if I want to package my code for other use.  alas, should I also do this for my own php include library functions?  Or should I still stick them into the same php location as my other php files?  In any case, if I want to go this route, presumably I would then customize the AppAsset class, included in the template, as explained in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html .
2. stick my files directly into `$basePath/web`, where $basePath is typically something like `/var/www/myapp/` (i.e., as $basePath/html/mine.html [and refer to it simply as href='/html/mine.html'], $basePath/css/mine.css , $basePath/js/mine.js, and $basePath/php/mine.php [and refer to it as `$basePath= \Yii::getAlias('@webroot'); require_once('$basepath/php/mine.php')` ])?
3. stick my local files where my php view code sits.  the advantage is that the files are close to where I will use them.  the disadvantage is that I may litter the view directories not only with php files, but also with my non-asset assets, even though they will be used only by these (my) php files.

it's a beginner's question for the google cache reference.  it's about best practice when getting started.  I can guess the answer, but we wouldn't want a novice to disseminate bad info.

Answer (score 2):

If you need your CSS and JS files only in one `view` or one `Controller` you have 2 choices:

**1-** Create a asset bundle [Here other guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) if you need it.

**2-** Use `registerJsFile()` from [View Class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail)

You can acces from controller using:

```
Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('js.path');
```

(Same with CSS files but using `registerCssFile()`)

With the `PHP`files I always try to convert the code to yii's MVC. If you have a entire library try to add it as a component. [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/) a usefull guide